Почему не видит переменную commands на 98 строке?
Почему то программа не видит переменную commands и выдаёт ошибку, на 98 строке не видит переменную commands
if commands.indexOf(message) != -1 {
       ^^^^^^^^


SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'commands'
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1281:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

const SteamUser = require('steam-user');
const SteamTotp = require('steam-totp');
const SteamCommunity = require('steamcommunity');
const TradeOfferManager = require('steam-tradeoffer-manager');

const Prices = require('./prices.json');
const config = require('./config.json');

function acceptOffer(offer) {
    offer.accept((err) => {
        community.checkConfirmations();
        console.log("We Accepted an offer");
        if (err) console.log("There was an error accepting the offer.");
    });
}

function declineOffer(offer) {
    offer.decline((err) => {
        console.log("We Declined an offer");
        if (err) console.log("There was an error declining the offer.");
    });
}

function processOffer(offer) {
    if (offer.isGlitched() || offer.state === 11) {
        console.log("Offer was glitched, declining.");
        declineOffer(offer);
    } else if (offer.partner.getSteamID64() === config.ownerID) {
        acceptOffer(offer);
    } else {
        var ourItems = offer.itemsToGive;
        var theirItems = offer.itemsToReceive;
        var ourValue = 0;
        var theirValue = 0;
        for (var i in ourItems) {
            var item = ourItems[i].market_name;
            if(Prices[item]) {
                ourValue += Prices[item].sell;
            } else {
                console.log("Invalid Value.");
                ourValue += 99999;
            }
        }
        for(var i in theirItems) {
            var item= theirItems[i].market_name;
            if(Prices[item]) {
                theirValue += Prices[item].buy;
            } else {
            console.log("Their value was different.")
            }
        } 
    }
    console.log("Our value: "+ourValue);
    console.log("Their value: "+theirValue);

    if (ourValue <= theirValue) {
        acceptOffer(offer);
    } else {
        declineOffer(offer);
    }
}

var commands = ["!help", "!prices", "!contact"]; //Список команд и ответов на них, 
чтобы не делать много условий
var anwsers = ["!prices - view a list of my prices\n!buy [n] [item name] (example: !buy 
1 Refined Metal)\n!contact - contact owner", "1 Strange Carbonado Botkiller Wrench Mk.I 
- 4 ref\n1 Strange Carbonado Botkiller Knife MkI - 3 ref", 
"https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561199091863367/"];

const client = new SteamUser();
const community = new SteamCommunity();
const manager = new TradeOfferManager ({
    steam: client,
    community: community,
    language: 'en'
});

const logOnOptions = {
    accountName: config.username,
    password: config.password,
    twoFactorCode: SteamTotp.generateAuthCode(config.sharedSecret)
};

client.logOn(logOnOptions);

client.on('loggedOn', () => {
    console.log('succesfully logged on.');
    client.setPersona(SteamUser.EPersonaState.Online);
    client.gamesPlayed([440]);
});

client.on("friend", function(steamID, relationship) { //Добавление в друзья
    if (relationship == Steam.EFriendRelationship.PendingInvitee) {
        steam.addFriend(steamID);
        client.on("friendMessage", function(steamID, message) {
            client.chatMessage(steamID, "Hello! Type !help in chat to view avaliable 
commands");
        });
    }
})

client.on("friendMessage", function(steamID, message) { //Ответ на команду
    if commands.indexOf(message) != -1 { 
        client.chatMessage(steamID, anwsers[commands.indexOf(message)]);
    }
    else if (message.slice(0, 5) == "!buy") {
        manager.on('newOffer', (offer) => {
            processOffer(offer);
       });
    }
    else {
        client.chatMessage(steamID, "Wrong command");
    }
});

client.on('webSession', (sessionid, cookies) => {
    manager.setCookies(cookies);

    community.setCookies(cookies);
    community.startConfirmationChecker(20000, config.identitySecret);
});

client.setOption("promptSteamGuardCode", false);


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Вы потеряли скобки для условия if commands.indexOf(message) != -1
